# How to increase spacing between sideway bar charts in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to increase the space between charts in this link however i have used minPadding/maxPadding in xAxis and  pointWidth: 90/pointPadding: 0 but nothing works. It seems to me that there is forced spacing at the top and bottom of the chart area which is causing this.
http://jsfiddle.net/j7NMC/2/

```
/*What i have tried */    
series:{
    pointWidth: 90,
    pointPadding: 0
}
xAxis: {minPadding:0, maxPadding:0,}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your data setup.  Instead of 3 different series, use 1 series and 3 categories:

```
series: [{
  data: [973,133,107]
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/j7NMC/4/

What this does for you:

1) eliminates that wasted space on the chart

2) eliminates need for legend by putting the labels right on the axis next to the bar (drastically improves usability of chart, makes comprehension much easier for user)

3) eliminates need for multiple colors for the bars (drastically improves usability of chart, makes comprehension much easier for user)

EDIT:{
you can try setting the groupPadding to 0 to remove some of the space, as the the 3 series you have displayed are grouped, and extra space is being added because of that.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, however the main reason why I did it that way was because i wanted to use the legend and the different colors. Are you saying that it is impossible to remove the spacing with the current way that i have my graph set up?

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional things that can be done.

I have to add though, that by purposely setting each bar to a different color and adding a legend that needs to be used to decode which bar is what....you are intentionally obfuscating the data and reducing the effectiveness of the chart.  FWIW

Comment: Thank you jlbriggs groupPadding is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The options need to be in the 'bar' section of plotOptions, and you don't need a series entry in plotOptions i.e. like this:

```
 plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                pointWidth: 10,
                pointPadding: 0
            }
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8dpf/

Comment: Thank you for that Steve however that only makes the bars smaller to accommodate the increase in padding between them. However if you notice from your example, the large spacing at the top and bottom of the chart (i.e. before the first bar and after the last bar) is still there and this is also what i want to get rid of. Any ideas?